# PDF417 - iOS Web App

Tags: android, ios, iphone, barcode, pdf417

I'm currently looking for a way to scan and read a PDF417 barcode via mobile device camera and have the data sent back to a URL via GET (or any method).

I originally implemented this on Android using the Barcode Scanner app which uses zxing - https://github.com/zxing/zxing/wiki/Scanning-From-Web-Pages.  This works really well for my app.

However, the same URL listed doesn't work on the iPhone.

Is there another app, like PDF417 from microblink, that I can use in a similar fashion to zxing on Android?

Comment: There is Scannrapp just for iOS http://scannrapp.com/

Comment: @ssasa This app seems to only scan drivers licenses and return the license data broken down in the URL

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Scannable, if i'm not mistaken they have several options for sharing files.

Comment: This app seems to only scan drivers licenses and has a 10 scan limit :(